# AES Lookup Tables implementation

Tags: c, encryption, aes

I am trying to implement the lookup tables in AES encryption (Rijndael). The formula is as follows ([based on their paper](http://csrc.nist.gov/archive/aes/rijndael/Rijndael-ammended.pdf)):

[image]

My Code is (for only one round):

```
for(j = 0; j < 4; ++j)
    {
        unsigned int xorOperation;
        xorOperation  = T_0_enc_2[input[0][j]]
                      ^ T_1_enc_2[input[1][(j-C1) % Nb]] // Nb = 4, C1 = 1, C2 = 2, C3 = 3
                      ^ T_2_enc_2[input[2][(j-C2) % Nb]]
                      ^ T_3_enc_2[input[3][(j-C3) % Nb]];

        xorOperation ^= (w[0][j + (Nb * (i+1))] <<  24)  // w[x] is the key array, (i+1) is the round number
                      | (w[1][j + (Nb * (i+1))] <<  16)
                      | (w[2][j + (Nb * (i+1))] <<   8)
                      | (w[3][j + (Nb * (i+1))]);

        input[0][j] = xorOperation >> 24;
        input[1][j] = xorOperation >> 16;
        input[2][j] = xorOperation >>  8;
        input[3][j] = xorOperation;
    }
```

the question is:

Does my code map exactly the formula? because when I cipher a plain text with a certain key, I don't get the expected cipher.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, a **specific problem or error** and the **shortest code necessary to reproduce** it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [MCVE].

Comment: If your code works fine, why are you asking us?

Comment: What is type of input[][] array? How do you declare it?

Comment: If both `j` and `C1` are unsigned int, then `j-C1` could be an overflow, and `(j-C1)%Nb` may be wrong. Does it seem possible to you ? What happens if you add a mulitple of Nb ? Could you try something like `(j+(C1*Nb-C1))%Nb` ?

Comment: @francis Good question about the type of `j`. That may affect the result only if `j` is signed. In that case the index value may be negative. For unsigned type the overflow gives expected result, since `Nb=4`. Anyway better to use protection adding `Nb`: `(j + Nb - C) % Nb`

Comment: If j is a signed value, and  assuming that abs(j-C1) < Nb, then use [(j-C1+Nb)%Nb) to avoid a negative result, or use an unsigned int or size_t for j.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out what was wrong in my code ... :)

i am using the input as an output which affects the results.. All I did to fix it is to use another array as an output and then copy the results back to the input once the round is done.

Thank you guys for trying with me....

Answer (score 0):

for creating the AES lookup table, you must apply the above code to all of the 256 input states per byte.